# selecting current value from array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

cant set the current user from my list

my array after submitting the form

```
[{"name":"Erich","surname":"Josh","email":"en@ss.com","age":"22","tel":"32423432432"}]
```

setCurrent user function

```
$scope.currentUser = null;

    $scope.setCurrentUser = function(name) {
        $scope.currentUser = $scope.users[name];
    };
```

I want to click on name and then display full information about that user, but i cant select current.

What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: plunkr/jsfiddle please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of what you doing is

```
$scope.currentUser = $scope.users[name];
```

Will be

```
$scope.currentUser = "Erich";
```

Because you get the value (name in this case is key)

The right solution, first declare the array of users

```
var users = [{"name":"Erich","surname":"Josh","email":"en@ss.com","age":"22","tel":"32423432432"},{"name":"Another","surname":"Josh","email":"en@ss.com","age":"22","tel":"32423432432"}];
```

Now rewrite the function setCurrentUser

```
$scope.setCurrentUser = function(name) {
  for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++)
    if(users[i].name == name){
      $scope.currentUser = users[i];
      break;
    } 
}
```

Now you have full information inside $scope.currentUser

Comment: tnx it worked. One question: is this bad syntax writing like this  ? `var users = $scope.users = [];`

Comment: It's Javascript, there's almost no such thing as "bad" syntax ;)

Comment: But you must understand that you can do var users = $scope.users = [], because javascript will see to current local scope and try to find $scope, for example if you will do the things such this: var a = b = [] javascript will create global object B its a not good practice)